# Automate scraping from a large list of URLs to extract specific text

Tags: screen-scraping

I am trying to automate scraping from a large list of URLs to extract specific text.

Website URLs could be grouped into sets where one set could be:

https://aecom.jobs/mackay-aus/senior-water-resources-engineer/624E99A0951B455E99C84ACEA0037A22/job/
https://aecom.jobs/sydney-au-aus/senior-track-engineer/EA2F94F54DE946C5B6FF47594CAC77E2/job/
https://aecom.jobs/sydney-au-aus/senior-sesa-engineer/856EB65733094A0D8467577640B9FC75/job/
https://aecom.jobs/sydney-au-aus/principal-ohw-engineer/ADDFF86B254841E1B00E6518B12A6778/job/

how can I do this through Azure or some better method, I have tried a number of website scraping software, but the scraping/outputs have not been useful.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is overly broad.

Answer (score 0):

I scrape job boards all the time with screen-scraper, and this doesn't seem like it should be hard. I don't understand where you are having difficulty: in requesting the URLs, parsing out the data you want, or saving the data.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I can perform part 1, but am having trouble with parts 2 and 3. I have managed to scrape URL links for jobs and have a large list file at any point in time using a number of web-scarping apps. How can I automate parts 2 and 3? Thanks